# Why am seeing all these Chinese proxy domains?

Tags: firewalls, proxy, botnet

Through a casual Google search I came to this Stack Overflow result. I clicked it absent-mindedly, could not connect through the server and saw that he domain was some Chinese government proxy server. Wait, what?

[image: Exhibit A]

Googling `proxy.hongze.gov.cn` directly, I found that Google has indexed many such sites:

[image: Exhibit B]

I am curious: what is this?

My first hypothesis is that Chinese government needs access to the full internet unrestricted, circumventing the Great Firewall through their own proxy servers, but left them accidentally open for Google to index? Is this plausible and somehow verifiable?

In any case, it makes me worry about being part of a Chinese botnet, because Google tends to localize search results and I am in Europe. Is there a way I could see whether my IP is indeed used for malicious purpose?

Comment: This is actually very interesting. According to my research this domain belongs to CHINANET Jiangxi province network.

Comment: Which is in AS134238 it seems. Just theory might just be right...

Comment: Which Google domain were you using when this appeared in your initial search results?

Comment: Although weird and worrying, there is a chance that this is not a security issue but a Google issue (hence, off-topic here). We are going to need more details to abe able to answer you on whether this is a security issue.

Comment: @Polynomial Google.com from a Dutch IP. It made me a bit paranoid about being part of a Chinese botnet possibly because Google tends to localize.

Comment: @schroeder Perhaps the implication of the above comment could re-open the question, and make it more amenable to concrete answers: 'how can I make sure I am not part of a botnet?'

Comment: There's no indication that you're part of a botnet. This looks like some kind of caching proxy that mirrors common websites. My guess is that it's related to restricted and monitored access to Western domains through China's state firewall. Google picking that up for indexing is not particularly surprising. For background, Hongze is not a large or politically pivotal place - it's a mid-sized district in Jiangsu province, mostly known for its gardens and culture. Running some sort of credential harvesting operation out of their local government infrastructure would be _incredibly_ weird.